# How to automatically move the content of UIScrollview

Tags: ipad, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollview and I want to scroll content of the scrollview automatically
How can we implement this

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085830/how-do-i-make-a-uiscrollview-scroll-automatically-at-a-certain-speed. May be this helps http://www.aaron.griffith.name/weblog/2011/02/23/scrolling-a-uiscrollview-programmatically/

Comment: try to add all the content inside your UIScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Timer` and change `contentSize` every second